# Find $E[Y\mid X=x]$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $(X,Y)$
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{4}\hspace{1cm} 0\leq y\leq x\leq 2$$
Find $E[Y\mid X=x]$

---

I know
$$\dfrac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}=\frac{x^2/4}{x^3/4}=\frac{1}{x}$$
My question is about the limits of integration,

I don't know if they are $[0,2]$
$$E[Y\mid X=x]=\int_0^2y\cdot\frac{1}{x}\,dy$$

or  $[0,x]$

$$E[Y\mid X=x]=\int_0^x y\cdot\frac{1}{x}\,dy$$

Comment: It is $0$ to $x$.

Comment: Why is $0$ to $x$ ?   .

Comment: Becasue $f(x,y)=0$ if $y >x$.

Comment: Ooooh thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you calculated is
$$
\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}=\frac{1}{x},\quad \color{red}{0\le y\le x\le 2}
$$

Hence for $x>0$,
$$
E(Y|X=x)=\int_0^2 \frac{yf(x,y)}{f_X(x)}dy=\int_0^x\frac{y}{x}dy=\frac{x}{2}.
$$
If $x<0$, then $f(x,y)=0$, and thus
$$
E(Y|X=x)=0.
$$